# yeoman nodemon watching to many files use --watch to reduce

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

Using the yeoman generator-angular-fullstack.

When launched with grunt serve:debug

I get:

[**nodemon] watching 38,946 files - this might cause high cpu usage. To reduce use "--watch".**

How \ where do I add this '--watch' so it only monitors specific folders?

Comment: I got this problem as well :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grunt nodemon's config format has been changed.

```
nodemon: {
  dev: {
    script: 'index.js',
    options: {
      args: ['dev'],
      nodeArgs: ['--debug'],
      callback: function (nodemon) {
        nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
          console.log(event.colour);
        });
      },
      env: {
        PORT: '8181'
      },
      cwd: __dirname,
      ignore: ['node_modules/**'],
      ext: 'js,coffee',
      watch: ['server'],
      delay: 1,
      legacyWatch: true
    }
  },
  exec: {
    options: {
      exec: 'less'
    }
  }
}
```

Please refer  https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-nodemon for detal.